# while loop in a function in apply

Tags: r, while-loop, apply

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df <- data.frame(A=1:10, B=3, C=17)
```

and I want to apply a function to each row of the dataframe which iteratively calculates a value based on the value of the row. My original data and the functions I use are much more complex, but the structure and the issues are the same here.

As an example, I use the following function to iteratively calculate the square root of A:

```
fun_iter <- function(df_input, diff=10){
              sqrt_iter <- df_input["A"]
              while(diff>0.01) {
               sqrt_iter_new <- (sqrt_iter + df_input["A"] / sqrt_iter) / 2  # approximate the square-root
               diff <- abs(sqrt_iter - sqrt_iter_new)  # difference between the iteration steps
               sqrt_iter <- sqrt_iter_new  # overwrite old value with new iteration
             }
             sqrt_iter[[1]]
             }
```

Then I can get the calculated value for one row with:

```
fun_iter(df[3, ])
```

which correctly returns the square root of 3. Furthermore, I can cycle through the dataframe with a for loop like this:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  print(fun_iter(df[i, ]))
}
```

Which gives me the square roots of all the values in the column "A". But, as I have a quite large dataframe, I would like to use "apply" or "map" or a similarly efficienty way to get the output, but it always returns this error:

```
apply(df, 2, fun_iter)

Error in while (diff > 0.01) { : Missing Value, where TRUE/FALSE is needed
```

So, somehow it seems as if apply has a problem evaluating the "while" condition within the function. Same happens to "map", "mapply", "do.call". Any hint towards solving this problem is highly appreciated.

Comment: `apply` is just a loop in disguise. It doesn't give you the same speed boost that vectorization would give (assuming that vectorization is possible). Even if you get the details right, you might be disappointed in the result.

Comment: try this  apply(df, 1, fun_iter)

Comment: It works, thanks! I seemed to be confused with the direction of "1" and "2" in apply, despite years of using it. Maybe something to do with the input format as described in the answer below. Thanks!

Comment: @John Coleman Thanks, vectorisation is not possible, unfortunately. I prefer `apply` to a for loop, so that I don't have to deal with writing each iteration step into a predefined dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the clarification in the comments we could iterate over the rows using one of these.  For those solutions that have names use `unname` on the result if you don't want them.

```
# 1
nr <- nrow(df)
sapply(1:nr, function(i) fun_iter(df[i, ]))
##  [1] 1.000000 1.414216 1.732051 2.000000 2.236069 2.449494 2.645767 2.828427
##  [9] 3.000000 3.162278

# 2
do.call("c", by(df, 1:nr, fun_iter, simplify = FALSE))
##        1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8 
## 1.000000 1.414216 1.732051 2.000000 2.236069 2.449494 2.645767 2.828427 
##        9       10 
## 3.000000 3.162278 

# 3
sapply(split(df, 1:nr), fun_iter)
##        1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8 
## 1.000000 1.414216 1.732051 2.000000 2.236069 2.449494 2.645767 2.828427 
##        9       10 
## 3.000000 3.162278
```

If we were sure that there were only numeric values in df then we could use `apply` like this.

```
# 4
apply(df, 1, fun_iter)
##  [1] 1.000000 1.414216 1.732051 2.000000 2.236069 2.449494 2.645767 2.828427
##  [9] 3.000000 3.162278
```

There are also a number of list comprehension packages (comprehenr, eList, listcompr) on CRAN.  For example,

```
# 5
library(listcompr)
gen.vector(fun_iter(df[i, ]), i = 1:nr)
## [1] 1.000000 1.414216 1.732051 2.000000 2.236069 2.449494 2.645767 2.828427
## [9] 3.000000 3.162278

# 6
library(comprehenr)
to_vec(for(i in 1:nr) fun_iter(df[i, ]))
## [1] 1.000000 1.414216 1.732051 2.000000 2.236069 2.449494 2.645767 2.828427
## [9] 3.000000 3.162278
```

### Old

We follow the comments below the question except we only pass `df["A"]` since `apply` will coerce the input to a plain vector and that could result in the row becoming character if any column is.  By using `df["A"]` we avoid that.

```
apply(df["A"], 1, fun_iter)
##  [1] 1.000000 1.414216 1.732051 2.000000 2.236069 2.449494 2.645767 2.828427
##  [9] 3.000000 3.162278
```

It would be easier if the function were written to accept `A` rather than `df` and also makes it more general as the column need not be named A and it also avoids the problem discussed above.  We have left the original names but you could consider using shorter names. The excessively verbose naming used in the function adds little and really obscures the code.

```
fun_iter2 <- function(A, diff = 10) {
  sqrt_iter <- A
  while(diff > 0.01) {
      sqrt_iter_new <- (sqrt_iter + A / sqrt_iter) / 2
      diff <- abs(sqrt_iter - sqrt_iter_new)
      sqrt_iter <- sqrt_iter_new
  }
  sqrt_iter
}
sapply(df$A, fun_iter2)
## [1] 1.000000 1.414216 1.732051 2.000000 2.236069 2.449494 2.645767 2.828427
## [9] 3.000000 3.162278
```

Comment: I used df["A"] because I have multiple variables as an input (20 so far and it will become more). Therefore I thought it was easiest to take the entire df as input. But as you point out "apply" changes it to charater it might be unavoidable to provide the variables in your way. Thanks!!

Comment: See revised answer.

Comment: Thanks for providing alternatives. `apply(df, 1, fun_iter)` was for me the fastest after removing the vectors with names. the `sapply` function was much slower (up to 18x slower!), somehow.

Comment: Perhaps it is related to the fact that the data is stored in a data frame and apply converts it to a matrix first.  You could try storing it in a matrix from the beginning given that it is all numeric.

Comment: Also since matrices are stored column by column if you store it as the transpose and then use `m <- t(df); apply(m, 2, fun_iter)` that might give a bit of extra speed too.

Comment: Actually, it made it a bit slower (by 16%) to use the transposed matrix compared to the dataframe. Curious!